# No option for adding New flutter Web Project in IntelliJ Dart Templates !!! Also tried Vs code, is asking for Which Dart template

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart, dart-webui, flutter-web

I'm trying to start a new Flutter project in Intellij as well as Vs code.
Intellij there is no option provided to add a new flutter web project in Dart templates.
Vs code whenever I select New flutter Web Project after accepting the stagehand it asks for the Dart template which is why I'm stuck.??
Please help soon??
[image]

Comment: Please file a request for this feature to https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues

Answer (score 3):

Since flutter 1.9 flutter_web is merged inside flutter, Follow the below steps to create and run your first flutter web App through IntelliJ IDEA.

1. Create a new flutter project.
2. Now change your flutter channel to master using `flutter channel master`
3. Upgrade flutter `flutter upgrade`
4. Install the flutter_web build tools `flutter pub global activate webdev`
5. Enable flutter web using `flutter config --enable-web`
6. Check available devices `flutter devices` and you will get a result like:

   ```
   Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.92    
   Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
   ```
7. Inside your flutter project create myapp using  `flutter create myapp`
8. Navigate inside myapp using `cd myapp`
9. Finally, run `flutter run -d chrome`

And you will be able to run your flutter web app into chrome. Hurray

Reference links: [Building a web application with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016974/no-option-for-adding-new-flutter-web-project-in-intellij-dart-templates-also/61184260#61184260) , [flutter_web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/OLD_README.md#limitations)

Comment: that also helps to run with IDEA, it adds to idea Chrome option

flutter pub global activate webdev

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the support for Flutter Web Apps was dropped in stagehand (that contains the dart templates). From [this commit on github](https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand/commit/5ea03a48a24de2e8de7d44a6fbc09f4734fd174e): (Dropping Flutter Web sample). Instead, [this wikipage](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-from-package:flutter_web-to-the-Flutter-SDK) shows how to migrate/create a web package in flutter from command line.

Answer (score 0):

- Create your project from command-line.
  Check out this tutorial. [flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)
- Then just open the project in IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score -2):

Install or Update the dart and flutter plugins in Intellij and/or VS Code

**For Intellij**

- Go to [mac] **Preferences>Plugins>Marketplace** and search for Dart and Flutter, install it.

**For VS Code**

- Go to **View > Command Pallet** and type in **Extensions: Install Extensions**
- then type flutter and install it

Its well documented in this link 
[Setup Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode)

Comment: I have followed the instructions but no use.