# Flutter web app option not found under dart templates while creating new dart project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, dart, flutter-web

**Version info
flutter doctor -v:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A582a,
    locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/dhavalkansara/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (11 days ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dhavalkansara/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

I want to create a new flutter web application through IntelliJ IDEA and for that, I don't found any option under the dart template as **Flutter Web App - a simple Flutter Web App**.

**Expected result:**

[image]

**Dart templates in my IntelliJ Idea:**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the options under `Flutter` group.

Comment: Yes, I have checked but we can create package/plugin/project only under the flutter project. There is no option for creating a web app inside flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since flutter 1.9 flutter_web is merged inside flutter, Follow the below steps to create and run your first flutter web App through IntelliJ IDEA.

1. Create a new flutter project.
2. Now change your flutter channel to master using `flutter channel master`
3. Upgrade flutter `flutter upgrade`
4. Install the flutter_web build tools `flutter pub global activate webdev`
5. Enable flutter web using `flutter config --enable-web`
6. Check available devices `flutter devices` and you will get a result like:

   ```
   Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.92    
   Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
   ```
7. Inside your flutter project create myapp using  `flutter create myapp`
8. Navigate inside myapp using `cd myapp`
9. Finally, run `flutter run -d chrome`

And you will be able to run your flutter web app into chrome. Hurray

Reference links: [Building a web application with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016974/no-option-for-adding-new-flutter-web-project-in-intellij-dart-templates-also/61184260#61184260) , [flutter_web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/OLD_README.md#limitations)

Comment: thank you this is useful but i want to know what is the best dev mode for us. our phisical device or virtual device like genymotion or web? what is your idea?